# Apple Photos: Read faces / people from photos.db the right way

Tags: macos, sqlite, photo

I am trying to read the photos.db SQLite database, that was generated by the Photos.app, included in Mac OS, in a personal project.

However, I am struggling with the structure. I didn't find an official guide, so I started with looking at the the table structures and comparing the data to what I can see in Photos.app.

**Reading albums:** This seems to be quite easy and is more or less about querying the RKAlbums table.

```
SELECT * FROM RKAlbum WHERE RKAlbum.albumSubclass = 3 AND RKAlbum.isInTrash = 0
```

**Reading photos from an album:** Seems easy as well, everything is more, or less included in the tables RKMaster (photos) and with a little digging on Stack Overflow was manageable.

```
SELECT * FROM RKMaster, RKVersion, RKAlbumVersion WHERE RKAlbumVersion.albumId = :album_id AND RKAlbumVersion.versionId = RKVersion.modelId AND RKVersion.masterId = RKMaster.modelId AND RKMaster.isInTrash = 0
```

**Reading people / faces:** Easy enough, the RKFace, and RKPerson tables will do:

```
SELECT * FROM RKPerson WHERE `name` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `name` ASC

SELECT * FROM RKFace `f`, RKMaster `m` WHERE f.personUuid = :person_id
```

**Combining faces and photos:** This is when things start getting confusing for me. I have a photo which I can see in Photos.app and als query in the RKMaster table. On that photo, there is a person with a face, which I can also see in Photos.app. However, I can't find the RKMaster.modelId in RKFace.imageModelId. Same goes the other way round: There are entries in RKFace.imageModelId, but many of them (not all) are not in RKMaster.modelId.

**Any ideas how the data is stored?** I am sure I am missing some tables to join the data or something.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
-- find people in a photo. specify photo name in where clause
select versions.*, persons.displayName, masters.imagePath from RKMaster masters
inner join RKVersion versions on versions.masterUuid = masters.uuid
inner join RKFace faces on faces.imageModelId = versions.modelId
inner join RKPerson persons on persons.modelId = faces.personId
where imagePath like '%P7251558.JPG';
```